# Is this a partial non injective non surjective function?

Tags: functions

I am trying to express a many to many relationship in mathematical terms. My problem can be represented as below.

[image: Many to Many example]

However, I will also have values like below.

- *4*,*5* in **A** domain with no mapping to B domain.
- *d*,*e* in **B** domain with no mapping to A domain.

I want to express this problem in mathematical terms. Is this a **partial** (*because of values 4 and 5 with no mapping*) **non injective** ( *1 and 3 are mapped to a*) **non surjective** (*d and e are left without mapping*) function?

If I am correct about the mathematical function, How should I express it in mathematical terms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is now, your "function" isn't really a function because it has multiple values ($f(1) = a$ and $b$). What you can do to fix this is look at a function from $A$ to $ \mathcal P (B),$ where $ \mathcal P (B)$ is the *powerset* of $B$. If you're not familiar, that means the set of all subsets of $B$. As an example, $ \mathcal P (\{1,2\}) = \{ \emptyset, \{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\}\}$.

So your new function takes an element in $A$ to the set of all elements associated with it in $B$. For example, $f(1) = \{a,b\}$ and $f(2) = \{b\}$. This new function really is a function because it is now single valued. And it is also defined for all elements of $A$; in your example $f(4)$ would be equal to $\emptyset$. Seen as a function $A \to \mathcal P (B), \ f$  is not injective because $f(4) = f(5) = \emptyset$. It is still not surjective because there is no element in $A$ that is associated to $4$ in $B$; there is no element $a$ such that $f(a) = \{4\}$, or indeed any set containing $4$.

However, the natural thing to do here is to just use a relation in the sense of set theory. This is just of set of ordered pairs. If the ordered pair $(a,b)$ is in our relation, we write $R(a,b)$ or $aRb$ for simplicity. Your relationship would be $R =\{(1,a),(1,b),(2,b),(3,a),(3,c)\}$. So the statement $R(1,a)$ or $1Ra$ would be true, but $R(b,3)$ would not.

I am not aware of any terminology like surjective or injective for relations, but it would seem quite natural to call a relation surjective if for any element $b$ in $B$, there is some element $a$ in $A$ so that $R(a,b)$ is true. Injectivity wouldn't be quite so natural to define, but you perhaps could call a  binary relation *left-unique* if no two elements of $A$ are related to the same element of $B$. Then you would have $R(a,b)$ and $R(a',b) \implies a=a'$.

However, none of this terminology is standard, and, again, I am not aware of any such descriptive terminology for relations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I want to generalize my problem using powersets, how should my equation look like? I mean, I am trying to frame the mathematical equation without the example.

Comment: Without more details about the specific problem, I would use a binary relation R. You could prove some properties of R if they apply to the problem. Then you could write statements like [R(a,x) and R(b,x) and R(a,y) implies R(b,y)] and formalize the problem you're working on.